# Dart private variable "unused"

Tags: dart

Both _pegHoleImage and _isPeg are private class variables yet _isPeg is seen by other functions but _pegHoleImage is not.  What is the difference?  I get the error message in Android studio that _pegHoleImage is not used, but I use it in the setImage() function.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class PegHole {

    PegHole({@required isPeg}) {
        _isPeg = isPeg;
        setImage();
    }

    Image _pegHoleImage;
    bool  _isPeg;

    toggle() {
        _isPeg = !_isPeg;
        setImage();
    }

    setImage() {
        _pegHoleImage = _isPeg ? Image.asset(kPEG_FILENAME) : Image.asset(kHOLE_FILENAME);
    }

    bool getPegStatus() {
        return _isPeg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting it but never using it.

Add this getter and it goes away.

```
Image get pegHoleImage => _pegHoleImage;
```